# Eigen values of organized lists in graph theory?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A graph can be represented as either a matrix or an adjacency list. Does this then imply that an adjacency list may be used to extract information about eigen values/vectors?

Comment: Is the question whether we can find eigenvalues from an adjacency list?

Comment: Yes. <insert proxy text>

Comment: Got it. Instead of converting it into a matrix, is there a process to find the eigenvalues/vectors from the list itself...

Comment: Yep that's it! <insert proxy letter>